# Revert changes for selected property on Edit

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, controller, asp.net-mvc-5

In Edit action, is it possible to revert changes made for particular property?

Consider the code:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Edit(ModelName model)
{
     if (ModelState.IsValid)
     {
         if(certainConditionMathes)
         {
             // revert model.PropertyName to original state
         }

        _dbContext.Entry(model).State = EntityState.Modified;
        await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
     }

     return View(evaluation);
}
```

As you can see `[Bind(Include = "...")]` will not fix this issue, because only under certain condition, we need to unbind it. Also, this is an extra server-side security measure; I am not rendering the field on View: `if(certainConditionMathes)`.

Comment: If the condition matches, get the original from the database and update the properties you want, then save the original (not the model)

Comment: Yes but `_dbContext.Entry(model).Entity.PropertyName` is giving me updated value. Is there anotherway to get the entry from DB? Can you post the answer, please?

Comment: No I mean, get the original, as you did in the GET method (presumably based on the ID of the `Entry`), then map the properties you want to update from the model to the original, and then save the original

Comment: @StephenMuecke fixed it by setting to `null`. :)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by setting the property to `null`, which produced the same effect as if the property was not *bound*.